# If number of replicas in a deployment is 1, and the deployment is bad, the deployment happens anyway, can i change this behaviour?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I was playing around with this: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/ in my infrastructure. I have a few deployments where I need replicas - but I have a couple where i only want one replica inside the deployment - however having an easy way to change the image version is great and required.

So I tried to see what would happen if you ran a broken update on a deployment with only 1 replica - if we do the following (from the documentation above):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

if we then run `kubectl create -f nginx-deployment.yaml`

we see 3 healthy running replicas.

If we then change the above file from `replicas: 3` to `replicas: 1` and run the apply command: `kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml` - we see 1 healthy replica.

Now - if we change `image: nginx:1.7.9` to something like `image: nginx:1.7.9broken` - and run `kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml` we see something like this:

```
$ kubectl get rs
NAME                             DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
nginx-deployment-2035384211      0         0         11m    <- this is the first one we created with 3 replicas
nginx-deployment-3257237551      1         1         8m     <- this is the broken one we made with 1 replica and a bad image name
nginx-deployment-3412426736      0         0         10m    <- this is the 2nd one we created with 1 replica

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                   READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-3257237551-od22j      0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          19s
```

So what seems to have happened here is the deployment has run, and created a new broken pod, and destryed the old one - something which the documentation, linked above, tells me should not happen?

My question is - **is there some setting i can change so that, even with 1 replica, the deployment will still work as intended, i.e. if the new pod created by the deployment is bad, it will keep the old pod running, or is there something else i should be doing when updating the images of single pods?**

note - this all seems to work fine on 2+ many replicas, and i tried to set the maxSurge value to like 5 to see if that made a difference, but it did not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you want to set [maxUnavailable](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/#_v1beta1_rollingupdatedeployment) (which defaults to 1) to 0. This should prevent Kubernetes from taking down any existing pods prior bringing a healthy one up. `maxSurge` only specifies how many pods exceeding the desired count you are willing to see getting deployed during a rolling upgrade. Since you only tried to roll out a single updated pod in your third deployment, the increase of `maxSurge` beyond the default value of 1 did not make a difference.

See also the [Rolling Update Deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#rolling-update-deployment) section in the documentation.